# How can I compare the data in an array of strings that is in one column of a table to JSON data within another column in the table?

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json, where-clause

I am having a hard time with all of it's complexities. For the sake of this question, I have a table with two columns. One column called names contains data like this:

```
["Marc", "Teddy", "Katie"]
```

The second column contains JSON data like this:

```
{"males":[{"name":"Marc","age":"32"},{"name":"Teddy","age":"8"}], 
 "females":[{"name":"Katie","age":"28"}]}
```

Is there a way in SQL to compare the strings in the array in the first column to the name field within the JSON data in the second column to attribute the age field in the JSON to the name strings in the first column?

I realize this is a complex/complicated situation, but any help with pulling data out of an array within a column, or pulling data out of a JSON in a column would be super helpful for me while I work on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that you need `JSON_CONTAINS()` along with `JSON_EXTRACT()` function in order to compare those columns such as

```
WITH t(col1,col2) AS
(
 SELECT '["Marc", "Teddy", "Katie"]', 
        '{"males":[{"name":"Marc","age":"32"},{"name":"Teddy","age":"8"}], "females":[{"name":"Katie","age":"28"}]}'
)
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(col2,'$.males[*].name') AS males,
       JSON_EXTRACT(col2,'$.females[*].name') AS females
  FROM t
 WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(col1,JSON_EXTRACT(col2,'$.males[*].name'))
    OR JSON_CONTAINS(col1,JSON_EXTRACT(col2,'$.females[*].name'))
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f27b015db95d3d186a3d1ce61ad2f036)</kbd>